# Need assistance with a simple Applescript Function for creating Project Folders that has suddenly stopped working

Tags: applescript

I use a simple Applescript function for creating client project folders for the work that passes through the studio.

It is a tried and trusted script that has been in place, and has worked perfectly, for around 7 or so years.

For some reason the script seems to have suddenly stopped working and will not include the job number within the final folder hierarchy. It now creates a folder called 'OK OK' with the correct folder structure inside albeit without the job number.

I have literally tried everything but now with a heavy heart and a tired brain I am looking for some help!

This is my current script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate

    set the jobnumber to "[jobnum] "
    set the jobtitle to "[jobtitle] "


    repeat
        display dialog "Enter the job number:" default answer the jobnumber buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
        copy the result as list to {the jobnumber, the button_pressed}
        if the jobnumber is not "" then exit repeat
    end repeat


    repeat
        display dialog "Enter the job title:" default answer the jobtitle buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
        copy the result as list to {the jobtitle, the button_pressed}
        if the jobtitle is not "" then exit repeat
    end repeat

    set the jobtitle to jobnumber & " " & jobtitle

    set deskpath to desktop

    make new folder at deskpath with properties {name:jobtitle}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Admin"}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Final Artwork"}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Links"}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " PDFs"}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Resources"}
    make new folder at folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Visuals"}

    make new folder at folder (jobnumber & " PDFs") of folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Old PDFs"}

    make new folder at folder (jobnumber & " Admin") of folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Supplier Estimates"}

    make new folder at folder (jobnumber & " Links") of folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Workings & Resources"}

    make new folder at folder (jobnumber & " Visuals") of folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Visual Links"}

    make new folder at folder (jobnumber & " Resources") of folder jobtitle of deskpath with properties {name:jobnumber & " Supplied Files"}

end tell
```

If anyone could shed light on why this has simply stopped working or would be kind enough to give guidance on how this could be fixed then I would be very grateful!

I don't mind if it is a completely new script ... I just need it to work again!

Thanks everyone in advance.

Matt

Comment: What changes have you made recently? Updated OSX?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dialogs are setting your variables as the `button returned` of display dialog instead of `text returned`. Instead of creating a list, which could change order, you should use the record that is returned to get your information.

You can change your repeat loops to the following, which will make sure that you're getting the right values from the dialog:

```
repeat
    set the jobnumber to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the job number:" default answer the jobnumber buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
    if the jobnumber is not "" then exit repeat
end repeat


repeat
    set the jobtitle to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the job title:" default answer the jobtitle buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
    if the jobtitle is not "" then exit repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough Darrick. Very quick response too that has solved a problem that was driving me insane! Much obliged ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as Darrick Herwehe mentioned, the result of the dialog box is returning the button returned first and then the text returned. So your variables are getting the opposite result than what you think. Here's how I would get the results of a display dialog. So instead of the "copy the result..." lines I would use this to make sure I know the order of the returned results. Or you could do it as Darrick Herwehe suggested and only get the text returned.

```
set {jobnumber, button_pressed} to {text returned, button returned} of result
```